# Read Android Manifest file using Java Code

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I want to parse Android manifest file using java code(not through Android code) and do some changes in that manifest file.

How can I do that??

Comment: I dont see a reason why should even try to do this. what do you want to acomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can change xml file using **DocumentBuilderFactory** class [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) is the sample code.